# Command curl malformed in shell script

Tags: shell, curl, ssh

Why when I use curl in ssh session it works well, but when I use it in a shell script it return an error.

In ssh session:

```
[root@XXXX scripts]# export host_name="http://XXXX:number_port"
[root@XXXX scripts]# echo "curl -u GET ${host_name}/application/listteam"
curl -u GET http://XXXX:number_port/application/listteam
```

But when I use it in a shell script:

```
list_team=$(curl GET "${host_name}/application/listteam")
echo "$list_team"
```

It retrun:

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: GET; Name or service not known
curl: (3) <url> malformed
```

I see that could not resolve host, but why when I try in ssh session it works ?

Some idea please ?

Comment: Is it because you use `name_host` instead of `host_name`?

Comment: You can use `set -x` in your script to see the actual commands that are executed, including parameter expansions.

Comment: @BenjaminW. no I edited my question

Comment: You need to show the complete script in a [mcve].

Comment: How can I use set -x ?

Comment: Just put it in your script as a command before you want the logging to start, and `set +x` after the commands to turn it off again.

Comment: Perhaps your script file contains CRLF line endings, and the host_name value ends with a carriage return character.

Comment: `curl GET` is not valid itself. Just leave out the `GET`, and add a `http://`. Or add a `-X` before the `GET`.

Comment: ...so, you could legitimately use `list_team=$(curl "http://${host_name}/application/listteam")`

Comment: ...re: "how can I use set -x?" -- another easy way is to run `bash -x yourscript` to invoke it with logging turned on from the point when it starts.

Comment: @CharlesDuffythe variable host_name is already declared in a config file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
curl -u GET ${host_name}/application/listteam"             # interactive
list_team=$(curl GET "${host_name}/application/listteam")  # non-interactive
```

In the first example, you have "-u GET". The "-u" parameter requires an argument, and `curl` is interpreting the word "GET" as that argument. It then goes on to interpret the next command-line argument as the URL to fetch.

In the second example, you just have "GET" without any "-u". `curl` is interpreting the word "GET" to be one of the URLs which it should fetch. You're getting an error because it can't interpret the word "GET" as a valid URL.

"-u" is used to specify a user name and password for the request. If you really need to specify the word "GET" as a user name, then your second example should have "-u GET" just like the first example.

On the other hand, if the word "GET" is supposed to be the type of HTTP request to make, then you should use "-X GET". Or just leave it out, because curl will do a GET request by default.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you are using name_host as variable in shell script instead of host_name.

Also make sure you can acess that variable through shell script.

Comment: Being speculative (and thus more a request for clarification than an authoritative response), this should be posted as a comment.